# opa5 sap.ui.test.matchers.AggregationLengthEquals not workung

Tags: sapui5

i am setting up some opa 5 tests on a sap.ui.table.Table and i need to test the result of applying a filter to the table.

i know home many rows should display in the result so i use sap.ui.test.matchers.AggregationLengthEquals to test.

but, sap.ui.test.matchers.AggregationLengthEquals only seems to return the total number of rows in the table, ie it includes the 'hidden' rows.

am i mis-understanding what sap.ui.test.matchers.AggregationLengthEquals does?

note, i am using a JSON data model.

cheers

pas.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify lets consider a table (`sap.ui.table.Table`) and we want to verify/test if it has **n** rows. We create the function `test` something like this:

```
test: function(tableId,n){
        var ag = new sap.ui.test.matchers.AggregationLengthEquals({name:"rows",length: n});
        var table = this.byId(tableId);
        result = ag.isMatching(table);
        return result;
}
```

To actually test use method `isMatching()` against your controller. The method above return a boolean value representing if indeed the table with `tableId` has the length of aggregation *rows* equal with **n**. Note that the method will consider all rows of the table (the model associated) not only the displayed ones.

I hope this answer helps to clarify your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. not quite sure how to use your suggestion. is the 'test: bit actually the check option in the waitFor method? an example showing how to use greatly appreciated. cheers, pas.